# How to rearrange subtasks using API?

Tags: asana

I created some sub tasks using the following API. But any new subtask I create, is getting added to the top of the subtask list in asana website.
I want the newly created subtasks to be at the end of the list. How to rearrange or to append to the list?

https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/12844760163515/subtasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this isn't supported via the API - we have plans to support something like the `insert_before`/`insert_after` parameter similar to on the `task/addProject` endpoint, but for subtasks.

It's not currently scheduled work, though I've added a note to this question so we can take that into account when prioritizing API work (and make notice when we ship it).

Comment: Has there been any change to this? I need the same thing for the same reason as the OP.

Comment: Yes, the ability to order subtasks [has been added to the Asana API](https://asana.com/developers/news/subtasks-stories-start-dates): _Just like when adding tasks to or reordering tasks in a project, you can now specify `insert_before` or `insert_after` when calling the setParent endpoint._